# Force synchronous query from PostGreSQL with NodeJS (and then return it to a function that parses that)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, promise

I have a database that holds a table of a list of users (and their respective usernames and passwords). I have a login system that runs a function that returns `false` when the user is not found and the username/password when it is found. That is then used in the login system but that's irrelevant.

My problem is that that function has to send a query to the database. But the callback actually can't return anything and so I can't just use

`await database.query('query things', data = await function(err, res) {function things});`

I tried declaring a variable and then inside the query callback setting that variable to the fetched data, and then outside of that query the `await` holds the rest of the code back, but it just returns `undefined`. The `await` does not do anything because of the multiple promise resolves (I think). So what ends up happening is the function returns `undefined` and the server crashes.

Is there a way that I can pass the fetched data through the function and back to the login system?

Structure:
login calls fetch function; fetch function queries database; callback sets a passthrough; fetch function receives that passthrough and parses it and returns things to the login.

Comment: does your lambda function return a promise?

Comment: You're doing the same thing this user is doing https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520001/691711 you should be using async/await OR callbacks, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for being helpful, internet. Unlike last time.

It turns out that because there is a callback inside it does not return a promise so async/await is not useable. I still wanted to not have the server instantly crash when an error occurred but try/catch works fine.